# Eclipse xdebug inspect SimpleXMLElement

Tags: eclipse, simplexml, xdebug

I'm using xDebug and eclipse. When I load a valid XML string with simplexml_load_string like this:

```
$responseXml = simplexml_load_string($response);
```

I can't seem to inspect the SimpleXMLElement variables. When I drill down into the variable, nothing shows. In screenshot below, I try to drill down into $responseXML but nothing shows:

[image: eclipse debugger variables tab]

I can definitely access a variable that I know is there:

```
$body = $responseXml->children('SOAP-ENV')->Body;
```

Below is my xdebug settings.

[image: xdebug settings]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

that's because SimpleXMLElement has some internal serialization methods. print_r and var_dump will produce the same. 
The best way to debug it is to convert it into a string using:

```
$responseXml->asXML()
```